# How to drag and drop selected row(s) in JqWidgets grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

I am displaying task list using JqWidgets grid. Now I have requirement that user can prioritize there task by drag and drop the selected task (one or multiple).

As you can see in the attached grid, user has selected multiple item from grid. Now user can priortize the items in the grid with simple drag and drop event.

[image]

I am sharing a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/6PL8H/) JSFiddle link

```
Can you please help me to do that...
```

For reference grid **[see this link](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/checkboxselection.htm)**

**I will appreciate you if you share a nice example of it to do the same in JqWidgets grid**

Thanks,

**~Chandan**

Comment: -Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @AnantDabhi thanks for your suggestion, I had added required details please check it once

Comment: @AnantDabhi There is no api implementation for this. You should do this with some hack.

Answer (score 0):

This example: [Drag jQWidgets Grid Records](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/dragdropmultiplerecords.htm?arctic) shows how to drag and drop records in jqxGrid. In your case, you will have to use the same approach, write your own logic what happens on Drop and I suggest you to use the jqxGrid's "updaterow" method to update existing rows on Drop.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I had already seen that; but in my scenario it is not fitting, can you please review  the JSFiddle link which I had shared with the question...